# CreateProcess calling cmd.exe incl. arguments with no showing (flashing) window?

Tags: c++, cmd, createprocess, windows-console

**The saga continues...**

I've searched the web, i've searched on StackOverflow, i found many hope giving answers/solutions, but somehow they have all failed (up)on me (including the ones related to ShellExecute(Ex) ).

**How to hide a (flashing) CMD window (incl. arguments) using CreateProcess??**

I basically want to call/execute a set of conditional/native `cmd.exe` commands (i.e. `FOR /F`, and `||`), but also an external command `FIND(STR).exe`. And this, **without** showing a (flashing) CMD window.

But even hiding something as simple as `"cmd.exe /C ECHO ...flashing window is bad..."` seems impossible to do.

**The code i've tried (including many variations related to the `dwFlags` and `wShowWindow` flags**

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()


{

    char cmdline[] = "cmd.exe /c ECHO ...flashing window is bad...";

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;

//  memset(&si,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

//  si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
//  si.dwFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
//  si.wShowWindow = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;

    CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR) cmdline, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

//  ExitProcess;

    return 0;

}
```

I don't want to rely on external programs i.e. .vbs (Windows Scripting Host) or shortcut tricks, but simply a standalone compiled .exe.

Is this (really) too much to ask, or am i doing it (completely) wrong?

**Thanks...**

Comment: Stop tag spamming. Read the descriptions of tags before just randomly adding those that look familiar. Two of the ones you added have nothing to do with your question here. Tags have a specific definition and purpose here.

Comment: The `main` entry point defaults to creating a console application. Are you overriding the linker's defaults?

Comment: Ken White: Perhaps the tags were too generic. Thanks for the advice. - eryksun: Why are you putting me to shame? ;-) I reviewed my linker's settings/options and noticed that _do not create a console window (-mwindows)_ was set to _no_ (i.e. disabled). After enableing it the window doesn't appear/show up anymore o_O **on a side note:** I've played with the offending linker setting before, but at that time it didn't work somehow... call it a mystery, but i still want to find out why it works now out of the blue. Would you mind it if i'll consider your answer as workaround, and not a solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** You also seem to confuse `CreateProcess` flags (its `dwCreationFlags` argument) with the member of `STARTUPINFO` structure. These are different flags, `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` should not be in `STARTUPINFO`.

You have to pass the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag, then the console window won't show. Originally I've answered that you have to redirect the standard handles which is not correct (but still highly recommanded).

Set `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` and fill in appropriate handles. If you are interested in the output of the process, create pipes, otherwise you can just open `nul` an pass that.

Comment: Redirecting the standard handles is separate from showing a console window. Internally there are really 4 standard I/O handles -- `ConsoleHandle`, `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError`. Console input/screen buffer handles are useless without being attached to a console, i.e. the internal `ConsoleHandle`. The console handle is also implicitly used for console functions that don't take a console buffer handle such as `GetConsoleCP`. The `AllocConsole` and `AttachConsole` functions potentially set all 4 handles.

Comment: If a `CreateProcess` call doesn't specify the `DETACHED_PROCESS` creation flag, then a console application automatically attaches to its parent's console, or it creates a new console when either the parent doesn't have one or specifies the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. If neither of the latter is used, then `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` can be used to create a new console that has no window. If a new console with a window is created, the window can be created hidden via `SW_HIDE` in the startup info.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes (i'm a newbie to this, guess i don't have to make a confession about it ;-) ). About the stdin/stdout redirecting: I assume you're referring to the **C++** way of redirecting and not the **CMD** way of redirecting? The **C++** way of redirection to _null_ is unknown to me (i've only seen examples of redirection the output to a file). A lot of this is still a mystery to me, but i'm learning it through failure, looking at people's code, and not being afraid to ask questions... I'll see what i can do, but it still sounds a bit abstract to me ;-)

Comment: Yes, i've meant C++ redirection. `nul` is a special file/device provided by Windows.

Comment: What i was thinking ;-)  .. Perhaps i'm wrong on this, but in case an IDE offers an option to hide (not show) a console window on execution, does the compiler use an alike/comparable method/way to hide the window (internally), as when using ShellExecute(Ex)'s and CreateProcess's hiding capabilities? (abeit the latter giving way more controlls/handles)

Comment: @eryksun There is not fourth handle (what you call `ConsoleHandle`). The standard handles themselves are the console buffer handles. `GetConsoleCP` uses the `StandardInput` handle. I've tried to hunt down these, handles and find out they behave in weird ways. There is a great write up here: https://github.com/rprichard/win32-console-docs

Comment: [`GetConsoleCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolecp) does not use the `StandardInput` handle. Use a debugger and check the process parameters, `?? @$peb->ProcessParameters`. The `ConsoleHandle` is an internal, undocumented, implementation detail. Having it set to a valid handle for a console is what it means to be attached to a console.

Comment: Prior to Windows 8, the `ConsoleHandle` is an LPC port shared between the console host process, conhost.exe, and an attached client process. Input/screen buffer handles are created and managed by the console and flagged by setting the lower 2 bits  (e.g. 3, 7, 11), which enables the API to route requests over special LPC-based functions instead of using the normal kernel I/O functions. Also, `CreateFile` is special cased to route opening "con", "conin$", and "conout$" to the LPC-based `OpenConsoleW` function.

Comment: In Windows 8+, the console uses the "\Device\ConDrv" device. "con", "conin$", and "conout$" are object symlinks to virtual files on this device, respectively named "Console", "CurrentIn", and "CurrentOut". The initial standard handles are files on the device named "Input" and "Output", and the `ConsoleHandle` is a file named "Connect". Other files named "Server" and "Reference" are used while connecting. Console input/screen buffer handles and the connection handle are kernel handles used with the standard NT I/O system calls `NtReadFile`, `NtWriteFile`, and `NtDeviceIoControlFile`.

Comment: Here's a step-by-step overview of [console initialization](https://pastebin.com/fd9h5JCg) at startup when a console application creates a new console using the newer ConDrv device implementation.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, there is a handle used to communicate with `ConDrv` / `csrss`. However try setting a input handle to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Your `GetConsoleCP` will change to zero. https://pastebin.com/9rJAHibZ . I also think the console handle is opened just once at the beginning, no matter how many consoles you open, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry. It's not a joke, but my stupidity. That means you are right.

Comment: Functions that access global data in the attached instance of conhost.exe (e.g. `GetConsoleCP`, `GetConsoleTitle`, and `GetConsoleWindow`) aren't related to an input/screen buffer, so the API uses the `ConsoleHandle` implicitly. Additionally, the console API in Window 7 always uses `ConsoleHandle` implicitly because the input/screen buffer handles are managed by conhost.exe, and internally the system routes all console calls (including a console `CreateFile`, `ReadFile` or `WriteFile`) over the LPC port connection to conhost.exe. In Windows 8+ with the ConDrv device it's more complicated.

Comment: In Windows 8+, `CreateFile`, `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` take the normal I/O path to the `NtCreateFile`, `NtReadFile`, and `NtWriteFile` system calls. Other console APIs use `NtDeviceIoControlFile`, either with an input/screen buffer handle or the "Connect" `ConsoleHandle`. The way it's implemented, the default "Input" and "Output" files on ConDrv work with any attached console. A "Connect" handle is specific to a connection to a particular instance of conhost.exe. If you detach via `FreeConsole`, this File is closed.

Comment: ...If you open "con" (Console), "conin$" (CurrentIn), or "conout$" (CurrentOut), these handles work with that particular console, and only that console. They continue to work if you detach via `FreeConsole` and then re-attach via `AttachConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ProcessBuilder. Here is an example of some code that I have that seems to work just fine. In my code below, the shellScript is a StringBuilder that I am dynamically creating that contains the command and it's parameters that I want to execute.

```
String[] scriptArray = shellScript.toString().split(" ");

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(scriptArray);
File outputFile = new File("/logs/AgentOutputLog.txt");
File errorFile = new File("/logs/AgentErrorLog.txt");
builder.redirectOutput(outputFile);
builder.redirectError(errorFile);
Process process = builder.start();
int errCode = process.waitFor();

//errCode = 0 means online
if(errCode == 0){
    success = true;
    break;
//errCode = 1 means offline
} else if (errCode == 1){
    success = false;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip/advice. I must admit that i'm quite new(bie) to this (C++), so i'll most likely fail in putting all the pieces of the puzzle together. But i really appreciate the help you're offering! If i'll manage to get my head around it, i'll let you know my findings. It's just that there are so many ways/methods to achieve something, which can make things a little complicated/complex (every method has its pros/cons). I'll definetely consider your offered code snippet, but you must understand that there can always be something better (more simple/minimalistic) around the corner ;-)